# localhost not being resolved after Tomcat startup, instead display weird GlassFish server message

Tags: tomcat, glassfish

I tried to locate *http://localhost:8080* in the browser, but I am getting the message the server has started up using GlassFish, I had stopped it, event uninstalled it restarted the PC, but still getting the below message.

I am getting this problem since today, I was using it on last Friday and it was working without any issues.

Actually there seems no GlassFish server, but it pretends to be the server.

Message:

> Glass Fish Server 3.1.2
>   Your server is now running

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the issue, it is some how taking the index.html for the glass fish event though it is unistalled, other that i could able to restart tomcat and calhost:8080/manager is working fine.